# Why is formdata displaying a file when there is no file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this form to upload an image for a user:

```
<form id="profileCreateForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="flex mb20">
        <div class="profile imagePreview relative border">
            <div class="btnContainer absolute top left">
                <img
                    class="buttonImg"
                    src="../assets/img/pic.png"
                    v-if="!fields.image"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="upLoadBtn absolute" v-if="!fields.image">
                <input
                    type="file"
                    name="photo"
                    accept="image/*"
                    class="imgUpload"
                    @change="handleImage"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="imgPreview absolute"
                :class="{ visible: fields.image }"
            >
                <img
                    class="picClose absolute"
                    src="../assets/img/close.png"
                    v-if="fields.image"
                    @click="removeImage(image, index)"
                />
                <img src="" id="previewImg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and then this function to handle the image so it displays what the uploaded image looks like before saving it:

```
function handleImage(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    const preview = document.getElementById("previewImg");
    function isFileImage(file) {
        return file && file["type"].split("/")[0] === "image";
    }
    if (isFileImage(file)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            preview.src = e.target.result;
        };
        fields.value.image = file;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        store.messages.push("Only image files are allowed");
        setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
    }
}
```

In the save method I am logging the formdata to the console and I see the photo has a File value even though there is no file selected for the file input. It gives it a type and a lastModified and size.

According to the MSDN docs the file input should show an empty string if no files are selected. Why is mine showing a file when I have not selected any files?

```
0: photo → File { lastModified: 1683451767954, size: 0, type: "application/octet-stream", … }
​​​
<key>: "photo"
​​​
<value>: File { lastModified: 1683451767954, size: 0, type: "application/octet-stream", … }
```